# NSJSONSerialization JSON parsing issue

Tags: ios, iphone, json

I have a problem with parsing JSON.
Here's my code:

```
     NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://itunes.apple.com/lookup?bundleId=com.clickgamer.AngryBirds"]; //This URL only for testing
     NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
     [request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];

    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError) {
        NSError *errorReturned = nil;
        NSURLResponse *theResponse =[[NSURLResponse alloc]init];
        NSError *jsonParsingError = nil;
        NSDictionary *jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers|NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&jsonParsingError];

        NSString *myString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

        NSLog(@"Data = %@ ", [[jsonArray objectForKey:@"results"] valueForKey:@"version"]);

    }];
```

In Console it prints out: `Data = (
    "3.4.1"
)`

But I want to have: `Data = 3.4.1` What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what is the JSON response?

Comment: The console listing is of an NSArray containing one NSString element.  The `()` characters indicate an NSArray.  If you want the element in the array, subscript the array.

Comment: @HotLicks Thanks for your advice, it is the same what staticVoidMain did in his answer and that fixed my problem.

Comment: It's important to learn now to read NSLogs from parsed JSON.  The JSON `[]` characters for an array come through as `()`, while the `{}` characters for a JSON "object" are still `{}` for an NSDictionary.  The `:` in a JSON "object" entry is replaced by `=` in the NSDictionary listing.  And JSON "object" keys and string values are quoted but NSDictionary keys and string values are not unless they contain "special" characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

seems `valueForKey:@"version"` returns an array with only one element.

try this:

```
NSLog(@"Data = %@ ", [[[jsonArray objectForKey:@"results"]
                                   valueForKey:@"version"]
                                 objectAtIndex:0]);
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
NSDictionary *jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&jsonError];
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but that what staticVoidMan supposed fixed my problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you try curl http://itunes.apple.com/lookup?bundleId=com.clickgamer.AngryBirds on the command line you can see from the output that the "results" object is an array so when you invoke the valueForKey method on the results array you get an array of all the @"version" keys in that array.

Example:

```
NSDictionary *test = @{@"results": @[@{@"version":@"1.0"}, @{@"version":@"2.0"}]};
NSLog(@"output: %@", [[test objectForKey:@"results"] valueForKey:@"version"]);
```

Output:

```
output: (
"1.0",
"2.0"
)
```

What you have to do is get the first object in the "results" array and get the version object from that eg.:

```
test[@"results"][0][@"version"]
```